# Table[x][y] is not working, is there an alternative?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to make a discord bot using Discordia but when I try to index a table using t[1][1] (parse[dataKey][message.guild.id]) it crashes. Can you please help? Is there another way or has anyone else experienced this? Maybe I'm just dumb.

```
local dataKey = message.author.id 
local file = io.open("./currency.json", "r") 
local parse = json.parse(file:read("*a")) 
file:close() 
if parse[dataKey][message.guild.id] ~= nil then
     parse[dataKey][message.guild.id] = parse[dataKey][message.guild.id] + addedCurrency 
else
     parse[dataKey][message.guild.id] = addedCurrency 
end
```

[solved]

Comment: Need some code for reference...

Comment: @J.Titus Relevant code should be
`local dataKey = message.author.id
local file = io.open("./currency.json", "r")
local parse = json.parse(file:read("*a"))
file:close()
if parse[dataKey][message.guild.id] ~= nil then
    parse[dataKey][message.guild.id] = parse[dataKey][message.guild.id] + addedCurrency
else
    parse[dataKey][message.guild.id] = addedCurrency
end`

Comment: Does the crash not produce some diagnostic information (logs, errors, stack trace)? Have you tried inspecting `parse` to see what its structure is?

Comment: What is the contents of `./currency.json`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I was stupid and malformatted currency.json.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).